# Accessing selection direction on an input element error

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, cookies, jquery-cookie

I'm trying to save the Javascript Array object in a cookie. But as it didn't work properly, I found the stringify() function in json.js file. Following is my code:

```
$(".save").on('click', function(){          
var lhb = [], csb = [], cons = [], vb = [],
      txt = $("#accordion").find('textarea').serialize(),
      lbs = $('.lh:checked').each(function(){ lhb.push($(this).val()); }),
     cbs = $(".cs:checked").each(function(){ csb.push($(this).val()); }),
     cs = $(".cons:checked").each(function(){ cons.push($(this).val()); });
     vs = $(".vul:checked").each(function() { vb.push($(this).val()); });
     scenario = { 
        "textArea" : txt
        "lbs" : lbs,
        "cbs" : cbs, 
        "cs" : cs,
        "vs" : vs
    },
    cardId = $(this).parent().get(0).id;
    save(cardId, scenario);
    retreive(cardId);
});
```

Now in the `save` function I convert the scenario into JSON object using json.js

```
function save(cardId, formData){
    $.cookie(cardId, JSON.stringify(formData), { expires: 7, path: '/' });
}
```

And this give me the following error:

`Accessing selection direction on an input element that cannot have a selection.`

Can anyone help me fix this error. Is that my approach is correct about saving the json array in to the cookie?

Thanks

Comment: I suspect it's coming from `find('textarea').serialize()`. Try using `find('textarea').text()` instead.

Comment: @Barmar: I tried it, but still having the same issue :(

Comment: In the part where you declare `scenario`, don't you mean to use `lhb`, `csb`, `cons` and `vb` instead of `lbs`, `cbs`, `cs` and `vs`? (because those are actually the jQuery object as returned by the .each() function rather than nice arrays)

Comment: $("#accordion").find('textarea').serialize() you cant apply serialize on textarea, I think only on forms

Comment: @MrFusion Thanks a lot for your comment. I found my bug and it now working perfectly. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".save").on('click', function(){          
    var lhb = [], csb = [], cons = [], vb = [],
        txt = $("#accordion").find('textarea').val();

    $('.lh:checked').each(function(){ 
        lhb.push($(this).val()); 
    });
    $(".cs:checked").each(function(){ 
        csb.push($(this).val()); 
    });
    $(".cons:checked").each(function(){ 
        cons.push($(this).val()); 
    });
    $(".vul:checked").each(function() { 
        vb.push($(this).val()); 
    });

    var scenario = { 
        "textArea" : txt,
        "lbs" : lhb,
        "cbs" : csb, 
        "cs" : cons,
        "vs" : vb
    }

    var cardId = $(this).parent().attr('id');

    save(cardId, scenario);
    retreive(cardId);
});
```

you have syntax error in scenario object, after txt there is no ',' also you didn't used correctly the serialize function, and wrong assignments in scenario objects

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me in this one. I found the bug from the previous comment. Also here if we have the .text() for get the textarea value, it wont work. better use .val(). Thanks